# SPA how to swap content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Cheers! Building a webpage from scratch using tornado io. I have different graphs and wanted to use some of the single page app magic. So I thought do a div and swap out the content doing:

```
<div id="chartType"> Chart goes here</div>
<a href="#" id="addContent">Load Graph</a>
<div id="maincontent"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('#addContent').click(function(){
   $("#maincontent").replaceWith("{% include graph.html %}");
   return false;
});
</script>
```

HTML does not seem to like the {% include graph.html %}
If I do something like $("#maincontent").load(/path/to/file) it keeps adding the content and not swapping it.

1. My question is how to swap the div content with different {% includes %}?
2. Is there a better way of doing this (Am I misusing the %includes% )?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe that `$("#maincontent").load(/path/to/file);` should work. I think you may be running afoul of caching, and so you may need to do this:

```
var setMainContent = function(path) {
    $.get({
        url: path,
        cache: false
    }, function(data){
        $("#maincontent").html(data);
    });
};
```

And then call your function in your click handler:

```
setMainContent(/path/to/file);
```

Answer (score 0):

What I usually do with very simple content swaps is use css to handle it.
For instance, if I have the content I want to show originally in Div A and the content I want to replace it with in Div B, by default I will have Div A set to 'display: block' and Div B set to 'display: none'. Then, to swap the content, use javascript to set Div A to 'display: none' and Div B set to 'display: block'.

```js
var divA = document.getElementById('divA');
var divB = document.getElementById('divB');

function hideDivA() { 
 divA.style.display = 'none';
}
function showDivB() {
 divB.style.display = 'block';
}

function swapContent() {
   hideDivA();
   showDivB();
}
```

```css
#divA {
  background: #74CFAE;
  color: #000;
  display: block;
 }
#divB {
  background: #555;
  color: #fff;
  display: none;
 }
```

```html
<div id='content-wrap' onclick='swapContent()'>
  <div id='divA'>Div A (initially visible content)</div>
  <div id='divB'>Div B (initially not visible content)</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your use case, you can also create a template and assign that into your DOM.

For instance.

```
<div id="runtime_area"></div>
<script type="text/html" id="page1">
  <b>Banner</b>
</script>
```

Then later

```
document.getElementById("runtime_area").innerHTML = document.getElementById("page1").innerHTML
```